# Unable to run the last script in sonarqube (./run-sonar-swift.sh -v)

Tags: swift, sonarqube

- xcodebuild clean build -workspace SGDPortalNativeFramework.xcworkspace -scheme 'NLO(Development)' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=13.3' -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
  xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "SGDPortalNativeFramework" does not contain a scheme named "NLO(Development)". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.
- returnValue=65
- set +x
  ERROR - Command 'xcodebuild clean build -workspace SGDPortalNativeFramework.xcworkspace -scheme NLO(Development) -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=13.3 -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO' failed with error code: 65
  admin@admins-imac-3 ops-native-framework-ios %